# Can Fancybox3 send a request param for iframe type?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have an fancybox in my admin panel which should show a form for add/edit menu item. That form lands on a different page and if I try to load this page as usual I will see all navbars, footers, etc. which is defined in normal context, but I'm using old ZF1 which has a thing named 'context' who can change current context depends on $_REQUEST['format'] variable.

Question a bit complicated, so there's short version w/o description of my problem:

**Is there a way to load iframe fancybox3 and send `format = 'fancybox'` variable to requested page?**

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom data when using ajax (fancybox by default sends `{ fancybox : true }`), but it is not possible for iframes.

Why don't you just load page like `mypage.html?format=fancybox` ?